# Image follow Background when resizing window screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking for a way to do the following:

I have two sections on my HTML page, the first has a background image property in its CSS class and also has a logo positioned in the bottom of this section and I have too a second section that is just a normal section with some text.

This picture shows the currently structure that I am using.

If the window screen is resized, the logo image has to follow the background image and keep its position in the bottom of the image.

[image: Webpage structure]

The last thing that I've tried:

```css
.background {
    background: url('../images/background-heroes.png') no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.background .logo {
    width: 20%;
    padding: 20% 0 5% 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.background h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="background">
   <div class="logo">
     <img src="images/logo.png">
   </div>
   <h1>LIVE YOUR OWN ANIME!</h1>
</section>
```

Unfortunately this solution that I've pasted makes the second section disappear.

Comment: Terry, just added my latest try! :D

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be about what you are trying to accomplish:

CSS

```
.background-image {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="background-image">
    <img class="logo">
</div>

<div class="another-section"></div>
```

Comment: The sample code was just provided, so this solution isn't perfectly tailored.  Hopefully the flex properties can still help you find a good solution!

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've just added a snippet with the code that I am currently using! :D

Please, if now you can have a better solution, I would appreciate to give it a try.